# Mac TexMaker: "File not found" when clicked on View PDF

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, mac

I am new to LaTex. I am currently using TexMaker for Mac on El Capitan OS. After saving my tex file, when I click on View PDF, "File not found" pops up. But if I first click on Tools>PDFLaTex and then click on "View PDF", then the pdf file appears in the right window of TexMaker. It seems that for every new tex file, I have to first click on Tools>PDFLaTex before viewing the pdf. Is this normal? Isn't there any way such that I won't have to first click on Tools>PDFLaTex everytime I want to view a new tex file? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes indeed, you must first compile your tex file to generate the pdf. You cannot see it before it is created.

Comment: I'm not acquainted with TeXmaker, but likely there is a button such as "Build & See" which will condense both operations.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for your response. There is something called "Quick Build" command in TexMaker which can be set as "PdfLaTex + ViewPDF". This is supposed to condense both operations. But in my case, it is failing to do so.

Comment: That's about what I had in mind. In this case, when you click "Quick Build" it does not get to "view", but (for the same file) if you first run "PdfLaTeX" and then "View" it does work? And when you run "Quick Build" and then "View" does it work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @gusburs I have figured out where I was going wrong. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Actually, instead of clicking on the arrow next to "Quick Build" to execute the command, I was clicking on "View PDF". Now, it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Ok, then welcome to TeX.SX. And I hope you have a good experience with LaTeX.

Comment: By the way, you can have a look at the [LaTeX Wiki Basics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics) to grasp better why these steps are necessary and what is going on with your files.

Comment: @gusbrs I, in fact, did go through LaTeX wiki basics. Was just clicking on the wrong button. :) Thanks again for your help :)